# didSelectRowAtIndex isn't working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to push a url string to my Main and it present my main view controller when I press on the cell.

This is my code.

```
 #pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Index Selected,%d",indexPath.row);

    MainViewController *View = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];

    [self.navigationController modalTransitionStyle];
    NSString *urltoPass = [NSString stringWithString:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellSubtitle"]];

    View.urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@",urltoPass];
    View.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Your question seems a little vague to me. You're tying to present a ViewController? It seems to me that the view you're manipulating is  the TableView?

Comment: Please clarify your problem, is the delegate function not being called? Is the view your trying to present not showing?

Comment: If the view you are trying to present is not showing, it's because you are not actually presenting it.  You set its transition style yet don't invoke [self presentViewController:View animated:YES completion:nil]

Comment: BTW: It's better practice to name variables starting with a lowercase character (view not View).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
– presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

on your View Controller to present it.

Comment: Yes, you were right i totally forgot to present the new view controller. This worked thank you!!